# How to make a text title where certain letters span two lines

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I can't figure out how to make this in regular css or tailwind, any help appreciated, tried using a grid but couldn't make it compact enough, example below. Example of what it should look like.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-2/3 grid grid-rows-2 grid-flow-col justify-center gap-y-0 self-center">
  <h1 class="text-[256px] font-bold font-mono flex md:text-light-blue row-span-2">PR</h1>
  <h1 class="text-[90px] font-bold font-mono flex md:text-light-blue items-end p-0">ESIDENT</h1>
  <h1 class="text-[90px] font-bold font-mono flex md:text-light-blue items-start p-0">IZE</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be much better to use an svg with a title. If the fonts don't load or the user changes the font / font size then this would break really easy.

Comment: Makes sense, how would you go about it? I've never really used svgs before.

Comment: add SVG to ::before. to it's content or background.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `grid`, I tried creating it with a mix of `flex` and `absolute` positioning. If you want to have a different `font size` you might need to tweak the `absolute` positions:

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text-[256px] font-bold">PR</div>
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute top-20 text-[104px] font-bold">ESIDENT</div>
    <div class="absolute top-44 text-[104px] font-bold">IZE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: first text]

The idea is to use `flex` in order to position both parts of the `header` next to each other. Then we position the second part of the `header` to fit the first part with absolute positioning (`top-20` and `top-44`).

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZpjQmDpBsH)

---

If you want to stretch your text you might want to use the `Scale` [utility](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale):

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="text-[256px] font-bold test scale-y-150">PR</div>
  <div class="relative">
    <div class="absolute top-[4rem] text-[104px] font-bold scale-y-[170%]">ESIDENT</div>
    <div class="absolute top-[12.5rem] text-[104px] font-bold scale-y-[170%]">IZE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: second text]

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z5cKJKrCbZ)

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted the line height and size of the smaller h1 and achieved the desired result.

```
<div className="w-2/3 grid grid-rows-2 grid-flow-col justify-center gap-y-0 self-center">
<h1 className="text-[256px] font-bold font-mono flex md:text-light-blue row-span-2"> PR</h1>
<h1 className="text-[115px] font-bold font-mono flex leading-[6rem] md:text-light-blue items-end p-0">ESIDENT</h1>
<h1 className="text-[115px] font-bold font-mono leading-[6.25rem] flex md:text-light-blue items-start p-0">IZE</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.main_div {
  display: flex;
align-items: center;
}

.main_div p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_div">
  <h1>PR</h1>
  <h5><p>ESIDENT</p><p>IZE</p></h5>
</div>
```